# regex to match hours delimited with am and pm

Tags: regex

I have come up with the following regex:

```
(\d*.*\d[am|pm])\w
```

to match the following example text:

> 8.30am-5.30pm
>   8am-5pm

I would like my regex to escape the hyphen and return the following matches:

```
8.30am
5.30pm
8am
5pm
```

unfortunately currently my regex matches the whole line in each case.

Comment: You can split with - like `^(.+?)-(.+?)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use "whole words" or alternation inside of a character class. It currently matches any character of: ( `a`, `m`, `|`, `p`, `m` ). A class matches any **one** character from a **set** of characters.

I would write the regular expression as follows:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?[ap]m
```

**Explanation**:

```
\d+        # digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
(?:        # group, but do not capture (optional):
  \.       #   '.'
  \d+      #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
)?         # end of grouping
[ap]       # any character of: 'a', 'p'
m          # 'm'
```

Or you could probably even simplify it to:

```
[\d.]+[ap]m
```